# Are there any games to Kindle Paperwhite 4?

Tags: kindle, kindle-paperwhite, software

I have a Kindle Paperwhite 4 and I just wonder, besides reading books, are there any games to play on it?

Of course a Super Mario might be too demanding to the display. However, I suppose a crosswords or Sudoku should be technically feasible?

Answer (score 2):

Games (and Apps) for Amazon Kindle Paperwhite are known as an Active Content and you can search Amazon Store for them [here](https://www.amazon.com/Kindle-Games-Active-Content/b?ie=UTF8&node=2534114011). Some of these games are for money, some are free.

However as stated [here](http://www.whichtogo.com/best-apps-games-kindle-paperwhite) they are fully supported on Paperwhite 1 & 2 and partly version 3, version 4 is not discussed at all. You have to test each and one you wish to try. Please leave a comment to complete my question on this topic.

Regarding controls, I found an article describing basic kindle paperwhite game controls [here](https://www.dummies.com/consumer-electronics/tablets/kindle/how-to-find-games-and-apps-for-your-kindle-paperwhite/). This can help you, if there are any games working on your device.